Increasing lag of replication slot
We have set up logical replication on AWS RDS. We have a subscription over a publication of most db tables. After the initial copy of tables that have been completed CDC started.
After some time we inspected the following log entry on the subscriber:
2024-09-24 05:08:26 UTC::@:[22213]:ERROR: could not receive data from WAL stream: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
2024-09-24 05:08:26 UTC::@:[705]:LOG: background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 22213) exited with exit code 1
2024-09-24 05:08:26 UTC::@:[22296]:LOG: logical replication apply worker for subscription "......" has started

The issue is that lag of this replication slot is continuously increasing after that time (it is currently 150gb) . We tried to enable / disable subscription and refresh publication but issue was not resolved. We then increased wal_sender_timeout and wal_receiver_timeout and the error disappeared from logs but the lag is keep increasing.
Some times the slot becomes active and restart_lsn moves but the lag is keep increasing.
Should we change streaming to parallel on subscription? Are there any caveats for this setting? Are there any other solutions?
Config settings on publisher:
┌───────────────────────┬─────────┐
│         name          │ setting │
├───────────────────────┼─────────┤
│ max_replication_slots │ 20      │
│ max_wal_senders       │ 35      │
│ wal_level             │ logical │
│ wal_sender_timeout    │ 300000  │
└───────────────────────┴─────────┘

Config settings on subscriber
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│              name               │ setting │
├─────────────────────────────────┼─────────┤
│ max_logical_replication_workers │ 8       │
│ max_replication_slots           │ 20      │
│ max_worker_processes            │ 20      │
│ wal_receiver_timeout            │ 300000  │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘


Are there long running transactions on the publisher? Lots of DDL statements?

No there are not any long running transactions on publisher. No DDL (ALTER TABLE etc) statements.

Hard to say with that little information. You can try 1) increasing logical_decoding_work_mem on the publisher 2) use streaming  on the subscription 3) increase max_logical_replication_workers on the subscriber. Depending on where the bottleneck is, that may help.

What is in the log on the publisher side?

We increased logical_decoding_work_mem and max_logical_replication_workers but it did not solve the issue. We then removed tables from publication and the lag gone away. Another question is about cpu. Is this because of the increased transaction logs that are kept to be replayed or due to pg_toast tables?
